# Trying to get a basic search bar up on my first react site

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to get my first react site up -- eventually it will be a parametric search of a product database, but for now I'm trying to just get a simple search bar up.  I am running into an error I don't understand.

I think I am nesting the styles incorrectly somehow, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'; // add
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'; // add
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

      search: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 'auto',
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
}),

export default function SearchAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <MuiThemeProvider>

      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>

      <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>

        <RaisedButton label="Material UI" />

      </div>

      </MuiThemeProvider>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get this error in the console when I run npm start.

```
  Line 39:1:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  37 | }),
  38 | 
> 39 | export default function SearchAppBar() {
     | ^
  40 |   const classes = useStyles();
  41 | 
  42 | class App extends Component {
```

Comment: change `}),` to `}));` - you need to close the `makeStyles` function and parenthesis around the JSX: `()`

Answer (score 1):

Line 37 I saw '}),' just use '}),' or '});'

Comment: I tried that and got this: `  Line 37:3:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  35 |     justifyContent: 'center',
  36 |   }
> 37 | });
     |   ^`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not closed your statement so just change **}),** to **}));**

Comment: That results in this error: ```  Line 37:3:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  35 |     justifyContent: 'center',
  36 |   }
> 37 | });
     |   ^```

Comment: That's why I said you should end the statement with **;** instead of **,**

Comment: @LevelChart8 And aslo you should lokk my **updated answer**

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed makeStyles function

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

      search: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 'auto',
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
}));
```

Try this

Comment: that works! but now I am getting this: `  Line 81:1:  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

  79 | }
  80 | 
> 81 | export default App;`

Comment: Are you trying to implement a class component or function component.. I see that inside exported function, you are writing a class. You should write either of one, not both.

Comment: I'm not sure which I should do.  What do you recommend?

Comment: Function component would be better as you are using hooks.

Comment: Remove these lines class App extends Component {
  render() { and corresponding closing brackets of these and try.

Comment: same error: `  Line 78:1:  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

  76 |   
  77 | 
> 78 | export default App;`

Comment: If you can create a codepen with your code, it would be better.

Comment: its my first time using codepen, but is this what you mean? https://codepen.io/levelchart8/pen/mdJjMEe

Comment: You have one more export default App at the end, remove it, if you are not using it.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from missing the close bracket as suggested by another user above, it seems you're trying to have two default exports (which i also got an error from), but only one is allowed per module.

How about the following? Passing down `classes` as props to the `App` component. The only error I have now is due to me not having installed material-ui.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'; // add
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'; // add
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({

  search: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
    },
    marginLeft: 0,
    width: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 'auto',
    },
  },
  searchIcon: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    pointerEvents: 'none',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
}));

export function SearchAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <App classes={classes} />
  )
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <MuiThemeProvider>

        <div className="App">
          <div className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
          </div>
          <p className="App-intro">
            To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>

          <div className={this.props.classes.search}>
            <div className={this.props.classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: this.props.classes.inputRoot,
                input: this.props.classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>

          <RaisedButton label="Material UI" />

        </div>

      </MuiThemeProvider>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i think that works, with the exception of these errors im now getting: `  Line 16:22:  'fade' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 18:24:  'fade' is not defined  no-undef`